# Is there a way to parallelize AES-GCM encryption?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, concurrency

Right now, I have 8GB of data to encrypt, and I've come up with a short python module (using pyCryptoDome) that will work. When I encrypt the data, a single core is almost 100%, the other only 5%. It takes, like, 10min.(Note: My computer is a 10-year-old dual-core intel i5.)
Module:

```
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES, ARC4
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes  
class AESCipher(Cipher):
@classmethod
def encrypt(cls, key, message):
    salt = get_random_bytes(AES.block_size)
    # use the Scrypt KDF to get a private key from the password
    private_key = hashlib.scrypt(
        key.encode(), salt=salt, n=2**14, r=8, p=1, dklen=32)
    # create cipher config
    cipher_config = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_GCM)
    # return a dictionary with the encrypted text
    cipher_text, tag = cipher_config.encrypt_and_digest(message)
    encrypted_dict = {
        'cipher_text': b64encode(cipher_text).decode('utf-8'),
        'salt': b64encode(salt).decode('utf-8'),
        'nonce': b64encode(cipher_config.nonce).decode('utf-8'),
        'tag': b64encode(tag).decode('utf-8')
    }
    encrypted = compress(bytes(dumps(encrypted_dict), "utf-8"))
    return encrypted
@classmethod
def decrypt(cls, key, message):
    enc_dict = loads(decompress(message))
    # decode the dictionary entries from base64
    salt = b64decode(enc_dict['salt'])
    cipher_text = b64decode(enc_dict['cipher_text'])
    nonce = b64decode(enc_dict['nonce'])
    tag = b64decode(enc_dict['tag'])
    # generate the private key from the password and salt
    private_key = hashlib.scrypt(
        key.encode(), salt=salt, n=2**14, r=8, p=1, dklen=32)
    # create the cipher config
    cipher = AES.new(private_key, AES.MODE_GCM, nonce=nonce)
    # decrypt the cipher text
    decrypted = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(cipher_text, tag)

    return decrypted
```

Comment: The main problem with AES in GCM mode is the gcm-tag at the end of encryption. When you start chunking you will get 2 or mode parts that need to get decrypted and later concatenated.

Comment: Beware that for GCM you don't want to encrypt more than 64 GiB - x of data, but I'd limit at 32 or 48 GiB. Make sure you understand [the limits of GCM mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode#Security). That said, you should take a look at the separate [`update()`, `encrypt()` and `digest()`](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#). You don't want to encrypt everything within memory, all at once. You don't want to compress encrypted data. And you certainly don't want to convert everything to base 64 either.

Comment: Finally, you may be better off using a stream cipher such as ChaCha20 with a MAC if your processor doesn't support AES-NI and/or GCM instructions yet, see [here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/chacha20_poly1305.html).